How to Implement API Token Generation, Verification, and Auto-Logout in ReactJS with Laravel API?
I am working on a web application with a ReactJS frontend and Laravel 11 backend. I am trying to implement token-based authentication where the user logs in, receives a token from the Laravel backend, and uses that token to access protected routes. However, I am facing a few issues related to token verification, auto logout when the token expires or becomes invalid, and token invalidation upon logout. I am using Laravel Passport or Sanctum for API token management.
Here’s what I’m trying to achieve:

Login: The user enters credentials, and on successful login, the backend generates and returns an API token that the frontend (ReactJS) stores.

Token Verification: On each request to protected routes, the frontend sends the stored token in the Authorization header. The backend should verify the token.

Auto-Logout: If the token is invalid or expired, the user should be automatically logged out and redirected to the login page.

Logout: When the user logs out, the token should be deleted both from the frontend (localStorage) and invalidated on the server side to prevent unauthorized access.



Issues:

Token Invalid/Expired: After logging in and generating the token, I sometimes get an error indicating that the token is invalid or expired when making requests. I’m unsure why this is happening, as the token is just generated.

Automatic Logout on Expiration/Invalid Token: I need to implement a way to automatically log out the user if the token expires or is invalid, redirecting them to the login page.

Token Deletion on Logout: I want to make sure the token is deleted from both localStorage and the server when the user logs out, but I’m not sure how to properly invalidate it on the server side.




Code:



ReactJS (Login):
```const loginUser = async (credentials) => { try { const response = await axios.post('/api/login', credentials); localStorage.setItem('token', response.data.token); // Store the token } catch (error) { console.error("Login failed:", error); } };`

ReactJS (API Request with Token):



const fetchData = async () => { 
    const token = localStorage.getItem('token'); // Get the token from localStorage 
    try { 
        const response = await axios.get('/api/protected-route', { 
            headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` } });
        return response.data; 
    } 
    catch (error) { 
        if (error.response && error.response.status === 401) { 
            // If token is invalid or expired, handle automatic logout here 
            handleLogout(); // A function to log out the user 
         } 
    } 
}; 



Laravel (Login Endpoint):


public function login(Request $request) { 
   $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password'); 
   if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) { 
        $token = Auth::user()->createToken('API Token')->plainTextToken; 
        return response()->json(['token' => $token]); 
    } 
    return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthorized'], 401); 
}



Laravel (Logout Endpoint):


public function logout(Request $request) { 
    $request->user()->tokens->each(function ($token) { 
        $token->delete(); // Invalidate all tokens 
    }); 
    return response()->json(['message' => 'Logged out successfully']); 
}


Token Expiration/Invalidation: How can I ensure the token is properly validated and not incorrectly flagged as expired or invalid?

Auto-Logout on Invalid/Expired Token: What’s the best way to handle automatic logout in ReactJS when a token is invalid or expired? Should I redirect the user after catching the 401 Unauthorized error?

Token Deletion on Logout: How do I properly delete the token from both localStorage on the frontend and invalidate it on the backend (Laravel) when the user logs out?



Additional Info:

I’m using Laravel's Sanctum (or Passport) for API token management.

I store the token in localStorage on the frontend and send it with each request in the Authorization header as Bearer {token}.

I’m using Axios to handle API requests in ReactJS.



